# Excel pivot table filter with text items in the value field

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am using the below code to filter on text called `(Missing Data)`, however after I've run the code the text items are still visible in the pivot table.

Notion: the pivot table are created from a regular table, and the `ServiceRange` column consists of a mix between text items and value items.

```
        For Each PI In PvtTbl_RegionalPeerGroup.PivotFields("ServiceRange").PivotItems
            If PI.Caption = "(Missing Data)" Then
                PI.Visible = False
                Stop
            End If
        Next PI
```

Comment: who are "they" ? Anyway you can't have a text as Value in Excel pivot unless it's a COUNTA() or similar.  In Access pivot you *can*. BTW you should tag your question `Excel`.

Comment: They are referring to the (Missing Data) PivotItems. The pivot table are based on a regular table where the "ServiceRange are a mix of values and text. Would it help if I made the (Missing Data) Blank?